# creating prototype using es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I created the following JS code:

```
;(function($w) {
    var Article = function() {
        this.articles = {};
        return this;
    }

    Article.prototype = {
        constructor: Article,
        loadArticles: function(data) {
            //do something
        }
    }

    $w.article = new Article();
})(window);
```

And when I to do the same function in ES6 i do the following

```
class Article {
    constructor() {
        this.modules = {};
        return this;
    }
    constructor() {
        return loadArticles.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    loadArticles(data) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I been using https://mohebifar.github.io/xto6/ to learn how to use/code ES6 without luck. Could anyone help me point out my issues?

Comment: Why do you have two `constructor` methods in the ES6 class? Also, do you realize that asking for off-site resources is off-topic?

Comment: oh really? - do you know any site where I can type that type of question then? I guess I'll be getting down voted soon

Comment: You didn’t even need to ask for such a resource. Just directly ask for help for a specific problem _here_.

Comment: I see so i can not have 2 constructor maybe thats one of my issues.

Comment: btw: when i run the ES6 code on the console i get *Unexpected token class*

Comment: _“There can only be one special method with the name `constructor` in a class. A `SyntaxError` will be thrown, if the class contains more than one occurrence of a `constructor` method.”_ — [MDN: `constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor). You get that error about `class` because almost no browser currently supports it.

Comment: The console in Chrome devtools does not directly support ES6 features such as classes. You can download a Chrome add-on which supports this, or run your code in some ES6-aware environment.

Comment: Classes are not supported in any of the current browsers or even node.js. In my opinion it's too early to be learning ES6 because it's completely useless for all practical purposes. It's useful if you want to get a head start or are curious but you need some sort of ES6-ES5 compiler in order to run your code. I know of several projects using ES6 for production by using compilers but I think it's way too early for production given that none of the ES6-ES5 compilers fully comply with ES6.

Comment: Where does `return loadArticles.apply(this, arguments);` suddenly come from? It's not in the first example. Also what is the actual question?

Comment: got it! - Thanks everyone for the help and points. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the ES6 of your first bit of code

```
class Article {
  constructor() {        // var Article = function() ...
    this.articles = {};
  }
  loadArticles(data) {   // Article.prototype.loadArticles = function() ...
    // do something...
  }
}
```